# Blazor BaseURI http vs https issue

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

I have the sample serverside Blazor app hosted in Heroku.

https://blazor-server.herokuapp.com

When switching between pages it defaults to the http version of the page, therefore giving me errors like this:

> blazor.server.js:8 Uncaught (in promise) Error:
>   System.ArgumentException: The URI
>   '**https**://blazor-server.herokuapp.com/counter' is not contained by
>   the base URI '**http**://blazor-server.herokuapp.com/'.

Comment: I think we would need to know a lot more about the configuration.

Comment: Do your ASP.NET Core server run behind the proxy server (e.g. Nginx / IIS) and uses `http://` instead of `https://`?

Comment: Also see https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/9692#issuecomment-489365575

Comment: Thanks for the comments.   the configuration is.   the basic blazor server side sample. dockerised.  and pushed to the basic heroku cloud.    I'll investigate the issue raised here and see if its relevant

Answer (score 3):

adding the following commands to the Configure method seems to have resolved it:

```
  app.UseForwardedHeaders();
    app.Use((ctx, next) =>
    {
        ctx.Request.Scheme = "https";
        return next();
    });
```